# How does one link between his/her various tiddlers?

Tags: tiddlywiki

I'm currently trying to figure this out. It seems a little complicated and I haven't found any resources that explain it clearly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 ways either via putting double brackets around it:

```
and a [[Test]]
```

and there will be a new one called "Test"

OR via using camelcase, see: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CamelCase

Just follow the default tutorial: http://www.blogjones.com/TiddlyWikiTutorial.html

In step 4 it will open "HowToMakeATiddler"